# how to replace existing user and password in Lists?

Tags: c#, replace

I'm currently having issue on editing an existing username and password that i stored in a list.

Declarations:

```
public static Administrator Cadmin = new Administrator("", "", "", "");
public static Staff Cstaff = new Staff("", "", "", "");
public static Administrator Ladmin = new Administrator("", "", "", "");
public static Staff Lstaff = new Staff("", "", "", "");
public static string NCName;
public static string NCPassword;
List<User> UserList = new List<User>();
```

Executing code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Which user would you like to edit?");
string ruser = Console.ReadLine();

bool Ustop = false;
while (!Ustop)
{
    foreach (User u in UserList)
    {
        if (ruser == Cadmin.CName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please key in the existing password of the selected username");
            string epass = Console.ReadLine();

            if (epass == Cadmin.CPassword)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Create new Administrator Username:");
                NCName = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("\nCreate new Administrator Password: ");
                NCPassword = Console.ReadLine();


                ruser.Replace(ruser, NCName);
                epass.Replace(epass, NCPassword);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Password that you key in is invalid!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Username that you key in did not exist!");
            Console.WriteLine("Please key in a valid username");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that you have issues on storing data in currently filled List, so here are one solution, use for instead if foreach, and then you can edit the specific member of the list, using it's index (I considered that CAdmin is inherited from User and User class has properties for CName and CPassword):

```
bool Ustop = false;
while (!Ustop)
{
    for (var i = 0; i< UserList.Count ; i++ )
    {
        User u = UserList[i];
        if (ruser == u.CName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please key in the existing password of the selected username");
            string epass = Console.ReadLine();

            if (epass == u.CPassword)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Create new Administrator Username:");
                NCName = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("\nCreate new Administrator Password: ");
                NCPassword = Console.ReadLine();


                u.CName = NCName;
                u.CPassword = NCPassword;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Password that you key in is invalid!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Username that you key in did not exist!");
            Console.WriteLine("Please key in a valid username");
        }
    }
}
```